# Computability of base-conversion for streams

Tags: computability, number-theory, base-conversion

With regular numbers it is always possible to convert them from one (integer) base to another. But what happens if we consider numbers for which their magnitude is not known in advance, or in other words, what if we are only allowed to work on a stream of digits (bits in case of base 2)? Then, by observaion:

- base 16 and base 256 are convertible, because for each 2 digits in base 16 we can confidently output one digit of base 256, and vice-versa. This can be generalized to bases $a,b$, where $a = n^x, b = n^y$.
- base 2 and base 3 do not seem to be convertible because with each new input digit the whole output can change.

So, the question is, which bases can be converted in this framework?

More formally:

For which $a: \mathbb{N}, b: \mathbb{N}$, 
there exist $f : [\mathbb{N}] \rightarrow [\mathbb{N}]$, $g : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, 
such that for all lists of digits $x: [\mathbb{N}], y: [\mathbb{N}]$ that represent the same number in base $a$ and $b$ respectively,
it's true that:

- for all $k \leq | x |$, $f(x[1..k]) = y[1..g(k)]$, and
- $g$ is unbounded and weakly increasing, and
- $f$ is computable.

PS: endianess does not matter, padding does not matter.

Comment: Hypothesis: I think its bases a and b such that a^n devides b^k or vice versa for some n and k. Maybe there's something more generic though. Might be worth attempting a proof.

Tiny addition, if you allow negative digits it tuns out you can always covert between bases. You basically always assume the largest possible outcome and then correct with negative digits.

Comment: Informal problem statement: You can always read the input until you've read the entire thing, keeping a copy of what you've read, and then at that point do the base conversion.  So the obvious answer is that it is possible for all bases.  Is there some additional requirement, such as that it is possible to do base conversion in a streaming fashion with only $O(1)$ memory, or something?  Formal problem statement: I'm not familiar with the notation $[\mathbb{N}]$.  Also, can you indicate whether the numbers are represented in big or little endian?

Comment: It could also potentially make a difference if the digits arrive in lower-order-first or higher-order-first (perhaps what you mean by endianness).

Comment: @Jake I assume your hypothesis is based on the fact that you know how to do it this more general way? Could you share the algorithm, it would be really appreciated. I thought about negative digits and why it is that they work, and I think it is because each number have infinitely many representations in such case. And so we can't probably use that fact :(

Comment: @D.W. informal problem statement: since we don't know the magnitude of the numbers, we cannot know when to output the result, so we have to resort to streaming. I guess it was not very clear in the statement, sorry. Formal problem statement: $[\mathbb{N}]$ means "ordered list of natural numbers" and syntax `x[1..k]` means list of first `k` elements from `x`. Endianness can be whatever is easier to deal with, so we can agree that digits come in either left-to-right or right-to-left order.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yes, and it is interesting how direction impacts the solvability (if at all), so I left that unspecified.